# Use multiple kernels in the same Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-console

Can I use multiple kernels in the same Jupyter notebook, such as I can choose specific code-block to run with specific kernel version?

**Example:**
I want to have two code blocks in the same notebook file(`.inypb`), one of them has Python 2.7 code and other code block has Python 3.0 code, both of them should run against its own kernel version.

Answer (score 1):

This SOS Polyglot Notebook extension for Jupyter should allow you to use multiple kernels in the same Jupyter notebook: https://github.com/vatlab/jupyterlab-sos