# Using multiple languages (or kernels) in the same VS Code Notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebooks don't be default support multiple simultaneous kernels in the same notebook, though there are extensions to do so (see [Use multiple kernels in the same Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494679/use-multiple-kernels-in-the-same-jupyter-notebook) and https://github.com/vatlab/jupyterlab-sos ).

Is there a way to do this within VS Code? That is, run one notebook with multiple kernels? Or even have two editors, one using one kernel and another using another? E.g. Run Python in some cells and Julia in other?